# Behavior of a failing SSD Drive

Tags: ssd, hard-drive-failure

I have a windows based computer with a SSD that I use for work (software development). The computer was issued to me by my employer and it's close to three years old now. As time has gone on in the last year, the computer has been giving me problems which are now getting much worse. The problem is mainly that it's just "slow" (slower than it was before). Slow to start programs, slow to save files, etc.

I recently ran NovaBench on it and found that the hard drive **write speed is 31 MB/s**. This seems to be far under par for a SSD (which I'm confident the computer has). (NovaBench Hardware Test Score 11)

**Is slowing write speed indicative of a failing SSD drive?**

Using NovaBench on a different computer with the exact same processor, the marks were all the in the ballpark except the hard drive. This other computer has a traditional HDD and that drive read **103 MB/s write speed**. (NovaBench Hardware score 26).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting slow SSD](http://superuser.com/questions/420707/troubleshooting-slow-ssd) also see [ssd running slow](http://superuser.com/questions/418933/ssd-running-slow) and [What could cause slow SSD performance?](http://superuser.com/questions/388677/what-could-cause-slow-ssd-performance).  Also, things like providing exact the make and model of the drive, and which OS you're running may help others help you.

Comment: The short answer to your question is no. That's an indication of a variety of things -- most likely more writes are requiring erases -- but a failing SSD is not one of them.

Comment: David, could you make your comment an answer. That is the answer to my question as I'm not trying to trouble shoot it but understand is it's failing or not.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps would either fix the issue or prove that your drive is indeed failing.

1. Back up your data
2. "Sanitary erase" the drive using tools and procedure specified by the
   drive's manufacturer
3. Create the new partition in size of 80% of total drive capacity
4. Do some benchmarking
5. Copy your data back
6. ...
7. Profit

Comment: What you're suggesting is not entirely viable. Last resource, maybe but as a method to prove it, I don't have the resources (time or backup tools) to execute this.

Comment: This is the most "viable" option you have. If the drive is failing - you need to back up an restore data... If the drive is "just slowing down" - there are no ways to fix it without destroying the data. So in any case it is backup&restore. There was a reason why I put benchmarking before data restoration - you can save that last step if the disk went bad.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your answer and time. Certinly informative and helpful. I didn't mean to dismiss.

Comment: This is when you are glad that you already have done step one so when you install the new drive or fix this one you can simply do an image restore.